# window.openで、phpのページを開きたいが開かない

Tags: jquery

Jquery 超初心者です。
HTML上のid=cdsrchボタン押下で、開きたい別画面があります。その別画面とは、呼び出し元同様phpのページで、以下JavaScriptで達成しようとしています。

function winOpenの第一引数がURLとなっていて、こちらを試しにhttp://yahoo.com/にすればしっかり表示でき、ありもしないページ名にすれば、そんなページは見つからない、という状況を確認しています。つまり関数にしっかり連携されているようです。

当該JavaScriptが納められたフォルダの一階層上に開きたいページ「cdselect.php」が置いてあり、以下ソースになっていますが、全く反応しません。
どなたかこの理由を教えて頂けませんでしょうか？よろしくお願いします。

（呼ばれる側の画面に何か記述が必要ですか？？）

```
$(function() {
  $('#calendar').datepicker();

  $('#cdsrch').click(function(){
    winOpen($('../cdselect.php').attr('action') , 300, 200);
    return false;
  });

  function winOpen(url, width, height) {
    if (width > 800) {
      width = 800;
    }
    if (height > 600) {
      height = 600;
    }
    window.open(url, '_blank', 'toolbar=no, location=no, directories=no, status=no, menubar=no, scrollbars=yes, resizable=yes, width=' + width + ', height=' + height);
  }

});
```

【別画面で開きたいページのソース】

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
    <title>コード選択画面</title>
  </head>
  <body>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`window.open`の第１引数に渡されることになる`$('../cdselect.php').attr('action')`、そもそも`$('../cdselect.php')`とはどのような値を期待されたのでしょうか？
意図通りに動作したYahoo等を試された時のコードはどうされたのでしょうか？ その際と同様な記述で`../cdselect.php`を指定すればそれまでのことと思われますがいかがでしょうか。